# Syntax error with javascript in razor

Tags: javascript, razor

I have the following code in a cshtml(razor) file, it has an error in visual studio 2012. If I add quotes around the last argument it will, but this produces the wrong javascript.

This has a syntax error wigaly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@{
    foreach (var i in Model()) {
         <text>JsModel.Add('@i.Name',  @(i.IsDeletable?"true":"false" ) );</text>
    }
} 
</script>
```

Output, that I want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    JsModel.Add(AName, true );
    JsModel.Add(AnotherName, false );
    …
</script>
```

This has no syntax error, but has wrong output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@{
    foreach (var i in Model()) {
         <text>JsModel.Add('@i.Name', '@(i.IsDeletable?"true":"false" )' );</text>
    }
} 
</script>
```

Output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    JsModel.Add(AName, 'true' );
    JsModel.Add(AnotherName, 'false' );
    …
</script>
```

How can I get it to work without an error?

Comment: `"@i.IsDeletable?'true':'false'"`

Comment: @A1rPun, no this still has quotes around it and the razor is illegal c#.

Comment: I have simplified the code in the question, and changed the js quote characters to reduce miss-understanding of what the problem is.

Comment: What do you expect to be the output? I expect "true" or "false"

Comment: @A1rPun I have updated the question to answer yours. Note: `i.IsDeletable?'true':'false'` is C# and there for `'` is not a valid quote character for strings, and would not fix the problem anyway.

Comment: And where exactly do you have the error? I pasted your code in my VS 2012 Express and there's no error.

Comment: There is a squigaly on one of the closing parenthesis. When I hover over it, it says syntax error. I wonder if it is resharper. It tells us about some extra errors, it may be over sensitive. I have noticed that it does compile, and run fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@{
    foreach (var i in Model()) {
         <text>JsModel.Add('@i.Name', @(i.IsDeletable?true:false ) );</text>
    }
} 
</script>
```

Comment: This does not work, same error as before, and will produce wrong javascript as well. When ToString is applied it will result in True or False (not true or false).